# ReportLab AssertionError: path must start with a moveto or rect

Tags: python, reportlab

I tried this using Python 3.6 and the current reportlab and svg2rlg libraries (as of this posting) and I got the error in the title.:

```
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg

c = Canvas(path+'To Print.pdf')
img27 = svg2rlg(path_to_.svg')
wd27 = img27.width/inch
ht27 = img27.height/inch
renderPDF.draw(img27, c, x=x27, y=y27)
```

It usually works just fine and I cannot figure out how to troubleshoot it.
I've tried searching for this error but cannot find it anywhere.

Here's the complete traceback:

```
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/Drive/Scripts/PDF.py", line 604, in <module>
    renderPDF.draw(img27, c, x=x27, y=y27)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderPDF.py", line 29, in draw
    R.draw(renderScaledDrawing(drawing), canvas, x, y, showBoundary=showBoundary)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderbase.py", line 201, in draw
    self.drawNode(drawing)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderPDF.py", line 54, in drawNode
    self.drawNodeDispatcher(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderbase.py", line 282, in drawNodeDispatcher
    self.drawGroup(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderbase.py", line 311, in drawGroup
    self.drawNode(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderPDF.py", line 54, in drawNode
    self.drawNodeDispatcher(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderbase.py", line 282, in drawNodeDispatcher
    self.drawGroup(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderbase.py", line 311, in drawGroup
    self.drawNode(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderPDF.py", line 54, in drawNode
    self.drawNodeDispatcher(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderbase.py", line 282, in drawNodeDispatcher
    self.drawGroup(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderbase.py", line 311, in drawGroup
    self.drawNode(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderPDF.py", line 54, in drawNode
    self.drawNodeDispatcher(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderbase.py", line 282, in drawNodeDispatcher
    self.drawGroup(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderbase.py", line 311, in drawGroup
    self.drawNode(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderPDF.py", line 54, in drawNode
    self.drawNodeDispatcher(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderbase.py", line 282, in drawNodeDispatcher
    self.drawGroup(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderbase.py", line 311, in drawGroup
    self.drawNode(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderPDF.py", line 54, in drawNode
    self.drawNodeDispatcher(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderbase.py", line 282, in drawNodeDispatcher
    self.drawGroup(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderbase.py", line 311, in drawGroup
    self.drawNode(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderPDF.py", line 54, in drawNode
    self.drawNodeDispatcher(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderbase.py", line 278, in drawNodeDispatcher
    self.drawPath(node)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderPDF.py", line 183, in drawPath
    isClosed = _renderPath(path, drawFuncs, forceClose=fill and autoclose=='pdf')

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/svglib/svglib.py", line 1075, in patchedRenderPath
    return original_renderPath(path, drawFuncs, **kwargs)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/shapes.py", line 996, in _renderPath
    drawFuncs[op](*points[i:j])

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/pdfgen/pathobject.py", line 127, in close
    self._code_append('h')

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/pdfgen/pathobject.py", line 36, in _init_code_append
    assert c.endswith(' m') or c.endswith(' re'), 'path must start with a moveto or rect'

AssertionError: path must start with a moveto or rect
```

Comment: Please make sure your code is correct. What are `x27` and `y27`? Also, what do you mean this usually works. From looking at the [source code](https://github.com/MatthewWilkes/reportlab/blob/ba223fd973db95cdc96839a8024bbf2388a531d5/src/reportlab/pdfgen/pathobject.py#L128), it seems like this error will always happen when `close()` is called.

Comment: maybe this file `svg` has mistake or use unusual values and module can't handle it.

Comment: Same here. SVG is produced from a matplotlib fig. In the failing case the axes contains no data. Figure is not empty, as there are legends etc. just no data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the last assert is over-zealous.

```
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/pdfgen/pathobject.py", line 36, in _init_code_append
    assert c.endswith(' m') or c.endswith(' re'), 'path must start with a moveto or rect'
```

The actual value of `c` at this location is "h" (as filled in by the call just above in the stack trace). If you just comment out the assert it works fine.

Please also let the nice people at ReportLab know so they can fix in the future.